# how to validate toggle is on or off in selenium

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing an issue in selenium + pure java. 
I have this toggle on screen and I want to know when it is active.
[image]
[image]

this is the elemt code when it is active:
[image]

and this is the code when not active:
[image]

the difference is in the class of the \button

I write this code:

```
public Boolean isDealActive() throws Exception
    {
       String test1 =  getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='switch_deal_status_toggle']//button")).getAttribute("checked");
       Boolean test2 = getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='switch_deal_status_toggle']//button")).isSelected();
       String test3 =  getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='switch_deal_status_toggle']")).getAttribute("checked");
       Boolean test4 = getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='switch_deal_status_toggle']")).isSelected();
        return  isElementSelected(DEAL_STATUS_XPATH);
    }
```

when I used the get attribute the results is null
when I used the is selected the results are false and not true.
the toggle now is ON, and I just get wrong results
can someone advise? 
** do not pay attention to the return statement, I will fix it after getting the correct answer from selenium

Answer (score 0):

try the following implementation

```
WebElement toggleBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='switch_deal_status_toggle']/button"));
String classAttributes = toggleBtn.getAttribute("class");
if (classAttributes.contains("ant-switch-checked")) {
    // checked
} else {
    // not checked
}
```